# How to send and recive serialized object in jxbrowser from java

Tags: java, jxbrowser

I have to send a serialized object from `java` to `javascript` with `jxbrowser` and I do this like this

```
String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(value);
JSValue window = browser.executeJavaScriptAndReturnValue("window");
window.asObject().setProperty(requestName, json);
```

As far as I know it will set a object in global window as `requestName`? It is true?
And in another way how I can read this object from java site. This code is ok?

```
JSValue window = browser.executeJavaScriptAndReturnValue("window."+requestName);
T t = objectMapper.readValue(window.toString(), clazz))
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Hi there are two aspects here.

**Javascript execution context**

**JSValue** that can be a plain value or a JavaScript object.

Once you invoke executeJavaScriptAndReturnValue your execution context is complete. And you can evaluate the returned object. This returned object can be a Java script object with functions in which case you can access it.

Lets say that your JavaScriptObject has a method helloWorld which accepts string.

```
JSValue document = browser.executeJavaScriptAndReturnValue("myJavascriptObject");
JSValue write = document.asObject().getProperty("helloWorldMethod");
write.asFunction().invoke(document.asObject(), "To Me");
```

This way we have passed the "To Me" string to the helloWorldMethod.

You can also set properties on the Object and invoke later another method. If this method uses this property, than within the next execution it will be taken into account:

```
JSValue document = browser.executeJavaScriptAndReturnValue("myJavascriptObject");
JSValue write = document.asObject().getProperty("helloWorldMethod");
document.asObject().setProperty("shouldISayGoodByeInstead",true)
write.asFunction().invoke(document.asObject(), "To Me");
```

The property shouldISayGoodByeInstead will be evaluated as part of the second execution which happens when helloWorldMethod is invoked, not during the first execution of executeJavaScriptAndReturnValue.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I really appreciate it. But I want to send a simple date (DTO class) between java and javascript. I don't want to invoke any methods. My idea is to serialized object from Java to JSON and sends it to javascript and receive object in the global window. And in other direction, I serialize an object in javascript to JSON and send it to java.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to set a JavaScript object through JSON. This can be achieved via the JSONString. You can check the example here: https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000013064-working-with-json

After that, you want to get the JSON object. For this case, there is a method

```
JSObject.toJSONString()
```

So if we change your sample in the following way, it should work as expected:

```
String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(value);
JSValue window = browser.executeJavaScriptAndReturnValue("window");
window.asObject().setProperty(requestName,  new JSONString(json));
JSValue window = browser.executeJavaScriptAndReturnValue("window."+requestName);
T t = objectMapper.readValue(window.asObject().toJSONString(), clazz))
```